# Unable to run a Shell inside a k8s pod

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

When I run the command `kubectl exec -it backstage-test01-5d877c7f54-425s6 -n customer-namespaces -- /bin/bash` it returns this error :

```
Defaulted container "linkerd-proxy" out of: linkerd-proxy, backstage-backend, linkerd-init (init)
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "eec3a58e120807f9dbea37e3c827850cc69690a4c0febd03ef6174b30a314fb7": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown
```

And here is the view I get in **Containers** tab for my pod.

[image]

I tried to execute a shell inside a kubernetes pod but I am getting an error saying that "bin/bash: no sush file or directory: unknown"

Comment: Hi there, would you able to check the Pod Log files - is the running ??

Comment: Looks like that container doesn't have bash

Comment: To reinforce @Paolo's comment: if the image is built around Alpine Linux, it likely won't have a `bash`, but it could have a similar `sh`.  It's also reasonably common to build images around static binaries (especially if the application is written in Go) and then install them into a very minimal image that includes no shell at all.  What you're trying may just be impossible with this image.

Comment: I'm also noticing the `Defaulted container ...` message; does specifying `-c backstage-backend` help you?  What's your higher-level goal with this `docker exec` command?

Comment: How about installing bash, if you want to run bash?

Comment: Issue is that I wasn't selecting the container I need to use since my pod is containing 2 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two containers in your pod:

- `linkerd-proxy`: Linkerd Sidecar Proxy
- `backstage-backend`: your container

Try specifying the container instead of using the default one :

```
kubectl exec -it backstage-test01-5d877c7f54-425s6 -n customer-namespaces -c backstage-backend -- /bin/bash
```

In order to avoid that in the future, add the following annotation, in your deployment within pod spec (available starting from v1.21):

```
kubectl.kubernetes.io/default-container
```

This annotation will guarantee that you access to the right container instead of `linkerd-proxy`

references :

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#kubectl-kubernetes-io-default-container
- https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/39899

Comment: Problem solved ! Need to specify what container I need to select. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When there is NO shell in your container image, like `cluster autoscaler`. One option is to run a shell in this container through [`ephemeral containers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/) and `kubectl debug`. Ephemeral container support went into beta in Kubernetes **1.23**.

Here is an example that creates an Ubuntu container, and attaches it  to a shell-less autoscaler pod

`kubectl debug -n kube-system -it cluster-autoscaler-xxxxx-xs5xr --image=ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

Some time this Pods get stack on PodsCreation and goes into a error loop, if you check it up you might be able to spot an error there.. You can easily check it with following command;

```
kubectl logs -f myPodName
```

From the log trail - make sure yourPod is running then to you can do something like;

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty myPodName -- sh
```

And then check if you can get into shell..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just because the environment has not installed bash yet?

For example (not sure about your pod env):

```
kubectl exec -it backstage-test01-5d877c7f54-425s6 -n customer-namespaces -- apk add bash
```

A quick check:

```
kubectl exec -it backstage-test01-5d877c7f54-425s6 -n customer-namespaces -- sh -c 'which yum || which apt-get || which apk'

# e.g. 
/sbin/apk
```